# Is there a key switch for Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, switch

I am trying to make a launch controller, which will turn on with a key. Like the one in this photo below:

[image: Switch Controller]

Comment: this is not an arduino related question and shopping questions are frowned upon here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for example [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1pc-mini-key-switch-Lock-Switch-Security-Power-Locks-phone-switch/32799985398.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.86.1e172335PfIKpH&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_5024915_10068_318_319_317_10696_450_10084_10083_10618_452_535_534_10304_533_10307_10820_532_10301_10821_204_10843_10059_10884_323_10887_100031_320_321_322_5728515_10103_448_449,searchweb201603_35,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=24658571-3e24-48b0-bd58-540bb5cb5392-12&algo_pvid=24658571-3e24-48b0-bd58-540bb5cb5392&transAbTest=ae803_4) for a key switch (see picture below).

As you can see it has two pins. If the pins are connected the switch is closed (same like a normal switch). So you can just connect one wire to VCC / 5V and the other via a high value resistor to a GPIO pin and check for LOW or HIGH.

(note: in practice it's possible to use almost any (electric/mechanical) component as long as the number of pins is not too high to be reasonably used by an Arduino).

[image]

Comment: Re “one wire to VCC / 5V and the other [...] to a GPIO pin”: for reading the state of the switch, you will need either a pullup or a pulldown resistor. You can use the internal pullup if you connect the other end of the switch to GND.

Answer (score 1):

A key switch is just a normal switch. What you do with it depends on how you wire it and code for it.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I meant where can I find one and buy it.

Comment: Not really well seen to provide buy link here. Any shop that cRry switches should also stock there. Ask your favorite local or online shop.